# DML trigger to create db backup when there is some changes

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement to create a database backup when there is some changes in the data,i mean if we are inserting/deleting/updating the existing data then Trigger need to execute to take the database backup and send an successful notification Email.

My Company requirement is to create a Trigger.

Comment: What database system?

Comment: no the user created databse

Comment: Database system - i.e. Oracle, SQL Server, DB2, Informix, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Access. Different database systems have different syntax for triggers and backups.

Comment: Sorry i am talking about sql database and version is 2012.

Comment: Why not just backup on a schedule?

Comment: as of now am doing that but we dont have exact track on when the changes r going to do and my boss requirement is to create a Trigger

Comment: Do you really need to perform backup of a database on each change  applied anywhere in your database? I would say that either you didn't write exactly what are your requirements here, or you misunderstood your boss. If that's not the case, your boss really doesn't know what he's doing.

Comment: Yes i really need to take backup of each change as we will be doing changes only twice in the month but we dont have exact time of change so we need to get done when we are modifying the changes

Comment: Can you please help me on geting the DML Trigger